# How do you write z-depth in a shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

This shader (code at the end) uses raymarching to render procedural geometry:

[image: shader output]

However, in the image (above) the cube in the background should be partially occluding the pink solid; it isn't because of this:

```
  struct fragmentOutput {
    float4 color : SV_Target;
    float zvalue : SV_Depth;
  };

  fragmentOutput frag(fragmentInput i) {
    fragmentOutput o;
    ...
    o.zvalue = IF(output[1] > 0, 0, 1);
  }
```

However, I cannot for the life of my figure out how to correctly generate a depth value here that correctly allows raymarched solids to obscure / not obscure the other geometry in the scene.

I know it's possible, because there's a working example here: https://github.com/i-saint/RaymarchingOnUnity5 (associated japanese language blog http://i-saint.hatenablog.com/)

However, it's in japanese, and largely undocumented, as well as being extremely complex.

I'm looking for an *extremely simplified* version of the same thing, from which to build on.

In the shader I'm currently using the fragment program line:

```
float2 output = march_raycast(i.worldpos, i.viewdir, _far, _step);
```

Maps an input point p on the quad need the camera (which this shader attached to it), into an output float2 (density, distance), where distance is the distance from the quad to the 'point' on the procedural surface.

The question is, how do I map that into a depth buffer in any useful way?

The complete shader is here, to use it, create a new scene with a sphere at 0,0,0 with a size of at least 50 and assign the shader to it:

```
Shader "Shaders/Raymarching/BasicMarch" {
  Properties {
    _sun ("Sun", Vector) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    _far ("Far Depth Value", Float) = 20
    _edgeFuzz ("Edge fuzziness", Range(1, 20)) = 1.0
    _lightStep ("Light step", Range(0.1, 5)) = 1.0
    _step ("Raycast step", Range(0.1, 5)) = 1.0
    _dark ("Dark value", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    _light ("Light Value", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    [Toggle] _debugDepth ("Display depth field", Float) = 0
    [Toggle] _debugLight ("Display light field", Float) = 0
  }
  SubShader {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Pass {
      CGPROGRAM

      #pragma vertex vert
      #pragma fragment frag
      #pragma target 3.0

      #include "UnityCG.cginc"
      #include "UnityLightingCommon.cginc" // for _LightColor0
      #define IF(a, b, c) lerp(b, c, step((fixed) (a), 0));

      uniform float _far;
      uniform float _lightStep;
      uniform float3 _sun;
      uniform float4 _light;
      uniform float4 _dark;
      uniform float _debugDepth;
      uniform float _debugLight;
      uniform float _edgeFuzz;
      uniform float _step;

      /**
       * Sphere at origin c, size s
       * @param center_ The center of the sphere
       * @param radius_ The radius of the sphere
       * @param point_ The point to check
       */
      float geom_soft_sphere(float3 center_, float radius_, float3 point_) {
        float rtn = distance(center_, point_);
        return IF(rtn < radius_, (radius_ - rtn) / radius_ / _edgeFuzz, 0);
      }

      /**
       * A rectoid centered at center_
       * @param center_ The center of the cube
       * @param halfsize_ The halfsize of the cube in each direction
       */
      float geom_rectoid(float3 center_, float3 halfsize_, float3 point_) {
        float rtn = IF((point_[0] < (center_[0] - halfsize_[0])) || (point_[0] > (center_[0] + halfsize_[0])), 0, 1);
        rtn = rtn * IF((point_[1] < (center_[1] - halfsize_[1])) || (point_[1] > (center_[1] + halfsize_[1])), 0, 1);
        rtn = rtn * IF((point_[2] < (center_[2] - halfsize_[2])) || (point_[2] > (center_[2] + halfsize_[2])), 0, 1);
        rtn = rtn * distance(point_, center_);
        float radius = length(halfsize_);
        return IF(rtn > 0, (radius - rtn) / radius / _edgeFuzz, 0);
      }

      /**
       * Calculate procedural geometry.
       * Return (0, 0, 0) for empty space.
       * @param point_ A float3; return the density of the solid at p.
       * @return The density of the procedural geometry of p.
       */
      float march_geometry(float3 point_) {
        return
          geom_rectoid(float3(0, 0, 0), float3(7, 7, 7), point_) +
          geom_soft_sphere(float3(10, 0, 0), 7, point_) +
          geom_soft_sphere(float3(-10, 0, 0), 7, point_) +
          geom_soft_sphere(float3(0, 0, 10), 7, point_) +
          geom_soft_sphere(float3(0, 0, -10), 7, point_);
      }

      /** Return a randomish value to sample step with */
      float rand(float3 seed) {
        return frac(sin(dot(seed.xyz ,float3(12.9898,78.233,45.5432))) * 43758.5453);
      }

      /**
       * March the point p along the cast path c, and return a float2
       * which is (density, depth); if the density is 0 no match was
       * found in the given depth domain.
       * @param point_ The origin point
       * @param cast_ The cast vector
       * @param max_ The maximum depth to step to
       * @param step_ The increment to step in
       * @return (denity, depth)
       */
      float2 march_raycast(float3 point_, float3 cast_, float max_, float step_) {
        float origin_ = point_;
        float depth_ = 0;
        float density_ = 0;
        int steps = floor(max_ / step_);
        for (int i = 0; (density_ <= 1) && (i < steps); ++i) {
          float3 target_ = point_ + cast_ * i * step_ + rand(point_) * cast_ * step_;
          density_ += march_geometry(target_);
          depth_ = IF((depth_ == 0) && (density_ != 0), distance(point_, target_), depth_);
        }
        density_ = IF(density_ > 1, 1, density_);
        return float2(density_, depth_);
      }

      /**
       * Simple lighting; raycast from depth point to light source, and get density on path
       * @param point_ The origin point on the render target
       * @param cast_ The original cast (ie. camera view direction)
       * @param raycast_ The result of the original raycast
       * @param max_ The max distance to cast
       * @param step_ The step increment
       */
      float2 march_lighting(float3 point_, float3 cast_, float2 raycast_, float max_, float step_) {
        float3 target_ = point_ + cast_ * raycast_[1];
        float3 lcast_ = normalize(_sun - target_);
        return march_raycast(target_, lcast_, max_, _lightStep);
      }

      struct fragmentInput {
        float4 position : SV_POSITION;
        float4 worldpos : TEXCOORD0;
        float3 viewdir : TEXCOORD1;
      };

      struct fragmentOutput {
        float4 color : SV_Target;
        float zvalue : SV_Depth;
      };

      fragmentInput vert(appdata_base i) {
        fragmentInput o;
        o.position = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, i.vertex);
        o.worldpos = mul(_Object2World, i.vertex);
        o.viewdir = -normalize(WorldSpaceViewDir(i.vertex));
        return o;
      }

      fragmentOutput frag(fragmentInput i) {
        fragmentOutput o;

        // Raycast
        float2 output = march_raycast(i.worldpos, i.viewdir, _far, _step);
        float2 light = march_lighting(i.worldpos, i.viewdir, output, _far, _step);
        float lvalue = 1.0 - light[0];
        float depth = output[1] / _far;

        // Generate fragment color
        float4 color = lerp(_light, _dark, lvalue);

        // Debugging: Depth
        float4 debug_depth = float4(depth, depth, depth, 1);
        color = IF(_debugDepth, debug_depth, color);

        // Debugging: Color
        float4 debug_light = float4(lvalue, lvalue, lvalue, 1);
        color = IF(_debugLight, debug_light, color);

        // Always apply the depth map
        color.a = output[0];

        o.zvalue = IF(output[1] > 0, 0, 1);
        o.color = IF(output[1] <= 0, 0, color);
        return o;
      }
      ENDCG
    }
  }
}
```

(Yes, I know it's quite complex, but it's very difficult to reduce this kind of shader into a 'simple test case' to play with)

I'll happy accept any answer which is a modification of the shader above that allows the procedural solid to be obscured / obscure other geometry in the scene as though is was 'real geometry'.

--

Edit: You can get this 'working' by explicitly setting the depth value on the other geometry in the scene using the same depth function as the raymarcher:

[image]

...however, I still cannot get this to work correctly with geometry using the 'standard' shader. Still hunting for a working solution...

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the project you linked to, the most important difference I see is that their [raycast march function](https://github.com/i-saint/RaymarchingOnUnity5/blob/master/Assets/Raymarching/Raymarcher.shader#L119) uses a pass-by-reference parameter to return a fragment position called `ray_pos`. That position appears to be in object space, so they [transform it using the view-projection matrix](https://github.com/i-saint/RaymarchingOnUnity5/blob/master/Assets/Raymarching/Raymarcher.shader#L207) to get clip space and read a depth value.

The project also has a `compute_depth` function, but [it looks pretty simple](https://github.com/i-saint/RaymarchingOnUnity5/blob/master/Assets/Raymarching/foundation.cginc#L24-L31).

Your `march_raycast` function is already calculating a `target_` position, so you could refactor a bit, apply the `out` keyword to return it to the caller, and use it in depth calculations:

```
//get position using pass-by-ref
float3 ray_pos = i.worldpos;
float2 output = march_raycast(ray_pos, i.viewdir, _far, _step);

...

//convert position to clip space, read depth
float4 clip_pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, float4(ray_pos, 1.0));
o.zvalue = clip_pos.z / clip_pos.w;
```

Comment: This does seem like the right way to do it, but practically speaking, the z component of clip_pos is always zero, regardless of the input ray_pos, so this doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: Actually.. it may... almost work. See the edit to the question above.

Comment: Depending on your render settings, Unity may actually be reading depth information from another pass. I've found mixed information on forum posts, but [this manual page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CameraDepthTexture.html) has some pretty good details.

Comment: Does not write to depth buffer, at least on Unity 5+

Answer (score 4):

There might be a problem with render setup.

To allow your shader to output per-pixel depth, its **depth-tests must be disabled**. Otherwise, GPU would - for optimization - assume that all your pixels' depths are the interpolated depths from your vertices.

As your shader does not do depth-tests, it **must be rendered before the geometry that does**, or it will just overwrite whatever the other geometry wrote to depth buffer.

It must however have **depth-write enabled**, or the depth output of your pixel shader will be ignored and not written to depth-buffer.

Your RenderType is Transparent, which, I assume, should **disable** depth-write. That would be a problem.
Your Queue is Transparent as well, which should have it render after all solid Geometry, and back to front, which would be a problem as well, as we already concluded we have to render before.

So

- put your shader in an early render queue that will render before solid geometry
- have depth-write enabled
- have depth-test disabled

Comment: @Doug did this anwer help you or do you still have problems? I'm sure we can work this out

Comment: I don't know to apply this answer; I mean, you might be right, but how do I *tangibly* use this advice to fix the shader in the question? I have tried your bullet points (Background+1, ZTest Off, ZWrite On) and it makes absolutely no difference that I can see.

Comment: You can see (with your suggested edits), the shader running in a project here: https://github.com/shadowmint/raymarching-tests

Comment: Hey Doug, I've been experimenting with your project. The main problem still seems to be the render order. I just can not get your shader to render before the opague geometry does. Using two seperate cameras I was able to force it, and the cylinder then really partially occludes your shader (there are also issues with your shader's depth output, but another story), but that is of course not a feasible solution. This is the current state however, I'll be looking into it further.

Comment: For what it's worth, I notice that i-saint's version renders in multiple passes to populate the g-buffer then render the appropriate color/alpha in another pass. I wonder if setting the alpha on the fragment (in my shader) forces it into the transparency render order for some reason and that is work around...